# How To Run Multiple Query From Return Result In Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have run one query to fetch data from database in model class and it is being shown after that in output i have got customer id and from customer id i want to fetch details of that customer.

Model Class:

```
public function viewcomplaindeails($id)
{
    $this->db->select('complainid,complainnumber,complainuserid,complaindate,complaintime,complaindescription,employeeassign,complainclosingdate,complainclosingtime,complainstatus');
    $this->db->where('complainid', $id);
    $query = $this->db->get('complain');
    return $query;
}


public function complain_get_user($complainuserid)
{
    $this->db->select('userid,name,email,mobilenumber,address,photo,usertype,city,state,createddatetime');
    $this->db->where('userid', $complainuserid);
    $query = $this->db->get('user');
    return $query;
}
```

Controller Class:

```
public function viewcomplaindeails($id)
{
    $this->load->model('dataout');
    $data['a'] = $this->dataout->viewcomplaindeails($id);
    $complainuserid = $data['a']->complainuserid;
    $data['user'] = $this->dataout->complain_get_user($complainuserid);
    $this->load->view('view_complain', $data);
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: How to write a join query?

Answer (score 1):

Use result_array() or row_array() to fetch the data from the database:

Result_array() used for fetching bulk data from table

Row_array() used for fetching single row of the data from the table

```
public function viewcomplaindeails($id)
{
    $this->db->select('complainid,complainnumber,complainuserid,complaindate,complaintime,complaindescription,employeeassign,complainclosingdate,complainclosingtime,complainstatus');
    $this->db->where('complainid', $id);
    $query = $this->db->get('complain')->row_array();
    return $query;
}


public function complain_get_user($complainuserid)
{
    $this->db->select('userid,name,email,mobilenumber,address,photo,usertype,city,state,createddatetime');
    $this->db->where('userid', $complainuserid);
    $query = $this->db->get('user')->row_array();
    return $query;
}
```

Comment: in view page you write in the value as value="<?php echo $a->fieldname; ?>"